# No such column: AGC.id Django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, operationalerror

I've been working with an existing datatable, so I create the models using `inspectdb`. My class doesn't have a primary key, so Django adds an automatic primary key named `id` when I `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Later, when I define the template, views, and URLs to see the class table at my website, there is an error like this one:

> no such column: AGC.id

I don´t know how to fix it, I'm new to using Django.

Model:

```py
class Agc(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.TextField(db_column='AREA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    periodo = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='PERIODO', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    demanda = models.TextField(db_column='DEMANDA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.

class Meta:
    db_table = 'AGC'
```

Template:

```
{% extends "despachowebapp/Base.html" %}

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Index</th>
            <th scope="col">Area</th>
            <th scope="col">Periodo</th>
            <th scope="col">Demanda</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
    {% if AGCs %}
        {% for AGC in AGCs  %}
            <tr>
                <th scope='row'>{{ Agc.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ Agc.index }}</td>
                <td>{{ Agc.index }}</td>
                <td>{{ Agc.area }}</td>
                <td>{{ Agc.periodo }}</td>
                <td>{{ Agc.demanda }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h1>No hay datos </h1>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
def index(request):
    AGCs=Agc.objects.all()
    contexto={'AGCs': AGCs }
    return render(request,'OfertasAGC.html', contexto)
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('webapp.urls')),
    path('prueba/',views.index),
]
```

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Django models must always have a primary key, you can use AutoField or BigAutoField or use another model field, but you will need to add the primary_key = True attribute.

For example:

```
class Agc(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    area = models.TextField(db_column='AREA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    periodo = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='PERIODO', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    demanda = models.TextField(db_column='DEMANDA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
    
    class Meta:
       db_table = 'AGC'
```

Comment: If you do not specify a primary key, Django will automatically create one with the name `id`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: Yes but in his database doesn't exist that field, he needs to create it or use another existing field as primary key.

Comment: no, normally the migrations create an `id` field. Furthermore it makes no difference specifying it explicitly, or let Django create the primary key field named `id`.

Comment: when i insert primary_key=True inside index there is another error and that error says remove the primary key or set primary key Null=False. So i don't know what to do

Comment: ERRORS:
webapp.Agc.index: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.
        HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.

Comment: Willem, José created the table by himself and then create the model with inspecdb command and he didn't add a primary key. José just set null and blank attributes to false and primary key set it true, and then django will use index field as primary key.